# Akka-HTTP: File Upload

Tags: scala, upload, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to implement a simple file upload using akka http.
My attempt looks as follows:

```
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem
    import akka.event.{LoggingAdapter, Logging}
    import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
    import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{HttpResponse, HttpRequest}
    import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
    import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
    import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Materializer}
    import com.typesafe.config.Config
    import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
    import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContextExecutor, Future}
    import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
    import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity
    import java.io._
    import akka.stream.io._

    object UploadTest extends App {
      implicit val system = ActorSystem()
      implicit val executor = system.dispatcher
      implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

      val config = ConfigFactory.load()
      val logger = Logging(system, getClass)

      val routes = {
        pathSingleSlash {
          (post & extractRequest) { 
            request => {
              val source = request.entity.dataBytes
              val outFile = new File("/tmp/outfile.dat")
              val sink = SynchronousFileSink.create(outFile)
              source.to(sink).run()
              complete(HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK))
            }
          }
        }
      }

      Http().bindAndHandle(routes, config.getString("http.interface"), config.getInt("http.port"))

    }
```

There are several issues with this code:

1. Files larger than the configured entity size cannot be uploaded:
   `Request Content-Length 24090745 exceeds the configured limit of 8388608`
2. Executing two uploads in a row result in a `dead letters encountered.` exception.

What is the best way to overcome the size limitations and how can I properly close the file such that a subsequent upload will overwrite the existing file (ignoring concurrent uploads for the moment)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For point 2, I think that `source.to(sink).run()` executes the operation asyschronously. It materialises a `Future`. Therefore your HTTP request may return before the file writing has completed, so if you start a second upload at the client as soon as the first request returns, the first one may not have finished writing to the file.

You could use the `onComplete` or `onSuccess` directive to only complete the http request when the future completes:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/http/directives/alphabetically.html

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onSuccess.html

EDIT:

For the content length problem, one thing you can do is increase the size of that property in `application.conf`. The default is:

```
akka.server.parsing.max-content-length = 8m
```

See http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/java/http/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks, using onSuccess solves the  'dead letters encountered' problem.

Comment: Have added an edit with an idea for the other problem

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, I have learned that setting the max-content-length to a larger value doesn't mean that the entire content is buffered in memory. So this is a safe way to solve this. I would have upvoted your answer but I don't have enough credits :-(

Comment: I think you can accept it as the answer though... :)

Answer (score 5):

Summarizing mattinbits comments, the follwing solution works:

1. Increasing `akka.server.parsing.max-content-length`
2. Using `onSuccess`

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
val routes = {
  pathSingleSlash {
    (post & extractRequest) { 
      request => {
        val source = request.entity.dataBytes
        val outFile = new File("/tmp/outfile.dat")
        val sink = SynchronousFileSink.create(outFile)
        val repl = source.runWith(sink).map(x => s"Finished uploading ${x} bytes!")
        onSuccess(repl) { repl =>
          complete(HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.OK, entity = repl))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```